# Continuity of cumulative distribution function holds if and only if the measure of a singleton is zero

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

At the very beginning of the classical book by Billingsley, *Convergence of Probability Measure*, I met the following statement (in the book is not reported as I am summarizing it here).

Let $\mathsf{P}$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. the classical Borel sigma-algebra) and consider the function
$$
F(x) \doteq \mathsf{P}(-\infty,x]
$$
Then $F$ is continuous at $x\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\mathsf{P}\{x\}=0$. To prove, consider that
$$
\{x\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[x-1/n,x+1/n]
$$
and so
$$
\mathsf{P}\{x\} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathsf{P}[x-1/n,x+1/n]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(F(x+1/n)-F(x-1/n))\quad (1).
$$
Now if $F$ is continuous we have $F(x+1/n)\rightarrow F(x)$ and $F(x-1/n)\rightarrow F(x)$ so that (1) implies $P\{x\}=0$. If, on the other way round, $P\{x\}=0$ from (1) and from the fact that $F$ can have only jump discontinuities (being monotonically increasing), we get
$F(x^{+})=F(x^{-})$.
Now, since all distribution functions are also right-continuous, we get
$F(x) =F(x^{+})=F(x^{-})$.

Just posting this for verification: is the proof correct?

Comment: It's better to show that $P(\{x\}) = F(x) - F(x-)$, which is what you have done.